# Where is Link at with Ilia in this screenshot?

Tags: zelda-twilight-princess

In the screenshot below, there is a brown wooden post behind them. I think the item they are giving out is a white horseshoe. But where is this place?

[image: Link and Ilia, an item, at someplace.]

Where is this location?

Answer (score 3):

The screenshot was taken at Kakariko Village inside the house of the village shaman, Renado, after showing the item in question to Ilia

> after which she regains her memory and reveals to Link, that this item called the *Horse Call* was meant to be a gift from her to him.

It is not a horseshoe, but a flute which can be used to call Epona without having to find patches of *Horse Grass*.

Answer (score 2):

The item in question is actually [Epona's horse call](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/wiki/Horse_Call).  It's the final link in a quest to restore Ilia's memory.

At this point in the story, Ilia is in [Sanctuary](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/wiki/Sanctuary_(Twilight_Princess)), in Kakariko Village.
(Sorry, I can't find a corroborating interior shot)